# how to solve microservice rpc call implement for frontend paging

Tags: microservices, grpc, rpc, web-frontend

I have two Golang microservices, a "task" service and an "app" service. The task service displays tasks, and since the tasks include some information about the corresponding app, the task service communicates with the app service via gRPC. The frontend needs to display tasks in pagination, for example, 10 tasks per page. However, each task requires a call to the app service to filter and retrieve the corresponding app information. This situation poses a challenge because if I query 10 tasks from the task service, after filtering them by calling the app service, there may be fewer than 10 tasks remaining. But the frontend table still expects to display 10 tasks per page. The "task" and "app" service's are in different databases. How can I solve this problem?

I expect "task" can call "app" service  that satify frontend's paging

Comment: Questions that can only be answered with opinions are discouraged on Stack overflow. Your question would benefit from a code description of the issue. Your question is likely to be down-voted and/or closed.

Comment: Given that your clients are unable to infer the number of Tasks|Apps that must be called to satisfy pagination, you have limited options. If you have t<10 Tasks in the result bucket, then you need to get 10-t more Tasks (and repeated the process) until the bucket is full or the Tasks list is exhausted.